# 29283. 00000 - "invalid file operation"

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsql-package

I want to load data from a CSV file, using UTL_FILE, but an error has occurred (see below), please note that I'm connecting to the database remotely and the CSV file is in my local machine.

```
29283. 00000 -  "invalid file operation"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to read from a file or directory that does
           not exist, or file or directory access was denied by the
           operating system.
*Action:   Verify file and directory access privileges on the file system,
           and if reading, verify that the file exists.
```

Is it necessary to put the CSV file where the DB is mounted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ora-29283 error on 11g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40481993/ora-29283-error-on-11g)

Comment: I understand that the Oracle 11g can only access files on the server where the DB is Mounted but is there any other way to load data from a CSV file using pl/SQL without depending on a third party programming language?

Comment: Can't you just create an external tables, based on the csv file and take it from there on? There's an excellent article here -> https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/external-tables-9i.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is local to your machine, your options are:

- transfer the file to the server, or
- make a location on your machine visible/mountable by the server, or
- use a client tool to load the data from your machine to the server

Assuming we'll be going with the last one, you can do this with:

SQL Developer
- Expand the "Tables" tab, right click on your table and choose Import

SQL Loader
- SQL Loader can be run locally (assuming you have the Oracle client) installed on your machine

Plenty of SQL Loader examples on https://asktom.oracle.com, or via the standard documentation

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-sql-loader.html